# Проблема 100К/1М

Tags: unix

Проблему 10К в unix системах решает epoll & kqueue. А какие технологии решают 100К и 1М проблемы?

Comment: wth «проблема 100K»

Comment: вдумчивое кодирование и тонкая настройка сетевого стека. 100к - 100к соединений

Comment: Вопрос бы понятнее задать надо ;)

Comment: горизонтальное масштабирование решает. на 1М соединений начнет отказывать бэкэнд, а ядро все также продолжит эти соединения принимать. проблемы в сетевом стеке не самое узкое место абстрактного серверного приложения на данный момент